# Sequences multiplying

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have this little question 
$
ln(Un+1)=ln(Un)-1$

$
U0=1$
Find P
Where P is 
$
P=U0*U1*U2*…Un
$
I have found this formula 
$
\frac{1}{e^{n!-1}}
$
 
Thanks

Comment: Is that $U_n + 1$ or $U_{n+1}$

Comment: When writing $ln$, did you mean $\ln$...?

Comment: Yeah I meant that

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you mean $\ln U_{n+1} = \ln U_n -1$, we have:

\begin{align}
\ln U_{1} &= \ln U_0 -1 \\
\ln U_{2} &= \ln U_1 -1 \\
&\cdots \\
\ln U_{n-1} &= \ln U_{n-2} -1 \\
\ln U_{n} &= \ln U_{n-1} -1\\
\end{align}

Sum all equations. Almost everything cancels and we're left with $\ln U_n=\ln U_0 - n= -n$.

Therefore, $U_n=e^{-n}$ and $P=e^p$, where $p=-(0+1+\cdots +n)=-\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.

Comment: Not sum ,I need the multiplying

Comment: Oh thanks I didn't notice that